# Need to cycle through and display each array value separately onClick - without jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am very new to JavaScript and trying to learn to do some functional things. I'm trying to get more comfortable with arrays. In this, I want the onClick in the HTML to cycle to EACH array value (color) and style the `<p>` with each one. Currently it just goes to the end, and I understand why it does that, but I don't know how to produce the result I want.

My (relevant) HTML:

```
<p id="pg">Hi, this is a string of text.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="change()">Click Me!</button>
```

My JS:

```
var colors = ['#3498db', '#e67e22', '#16a085', '#f39c12', '#2c3e50', '#7f8c8d', '#2980b9'];

function change()
{
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        x=document.getElementById("pg"); // Find the element
        x.style.color=colors[i];          // Change the style
    }
}
```

Should I even use loops for this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you wanting to style each word in the `p` element; or are you wanting to style different `p` elements?

Comment: what are you trying to do? `x=document.getElementById("pg");` is always going to get the same element..

Comment: The color will not update until the page is no longer busy running your JavaScript method, that's why you only get the last color.

Comment: And one other question, not necessarily related. My external script, which is linked correctly to my HTML doc continues to tell me that my variable: `var print = document.getElementById('pg');` is null. But when it's within a function, it's fine...

Comment: I want the same <p> to be styled with each color in the array, cycling through by clicking the button.

Comment: It doesn't just go to the end. There is no delay in between setting the color, so of course you don't see the ones in between.

Comment: @alex.mo.07 Update your question with these new details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use either global variable below, or alternatively run a loop to find the color and get next. Here is the first approach:

```
var colors = ['#3498db', '#e67e22', '#16a085', '#f39c12', '#2c3e50', '#7f8c8d', '#2980b9'];
var i = 0;

function change()
{
    x=document.getElementById("pg"); 
    x.style.color=colors[i++];
    if(i == colors.length) i = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a different approach, but parses the array in a new way I didn't know you could.

Comment: You could've just done `x.style.color = colors[i = ++i % colors.length];` but doing it like this might be more clear to read.

Comment: @KevinBowersox since it is set to i++ it is going to reach length by the time it comes to the if condition

Comment: @KevinBowersox He would need to do `++i` for that to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var colors = ['#3498db', '#e67e22', '#16a085', '#f39c12', '#2c3e50', '#7f8c8d', '#2980b9'];

function change()
{
    setColor(0);
}

function setColor(i) {
    if(i >= colors.length);
        return;

    document.getElementById("pg").style.color = colors[i];

    setTimeout(function() {
        setColor(i + 1);
    }, 1000);
}
```

You can change the second parameter of setTimeout to decide how many milliseconds to wait before changing color again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important pieces in this code.  The first is the timeout which changes the color each second.  The second is that a closure is created to assure that the color variable is not changed within the function passed to `setTimeout` during the iterations of the loop.

```
var colors = ['#3498db', '#e67e22', '#16a085', '#f39c12', '#2c3e50', '#7f8c8d', '#2980b9'];

var timeouts = [];
function change()
{
    clearTimeouts()
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        var timeout = setTimeout(changeColor(colors[i]), 1000 * i);
        timeouts.push(timeout);
    }
}

function changeColor(color){
    return function(){
        var x=document.getElementById("pg"); // Find the element
        x.style.color=color;
    };
}

function clearTimeouts(){
    for(var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++){
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4ryGJ/1

**If you would prefer to only change the color on each click**

```
var colors = ['#3498db', '#e67e22', '#16a085', '#f39c12', '#2c3e50', '#7f8c8d', '#2980b9'];

var color = 0;
function change()
{
    color = (color == colors.length -1) ? 0: color;
        x=document.getElementById("pg"); // Find the element
        x.style.color=colors[++color];
}
```

Comment: You should clear the previous timeout in case the button is clicked again before the last loop finishes.

Comment: @Jay and the `changeColor` function returns a function which is called.  It is forming a closure.

Comment: This works great, thank you. Is there any way to ONLY change the color on the click event? Instead of a timed transition?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yep. You'd need to clear them all. Use an array I guess =/ You might be able to assume they are all sequential too.

Comment: @alex.mo.07 What do you mean? Like choose a new color from the array each time you click it? You could do `changeColor(colors[lastColorIndex % colors.length]);` where `lastColorIndex is a sequentially based index that you keep.

Comment: @crush Added the change to the initial post to handle clearing the timeouts.

Comment: @alex.mo.07  Added updated code that will change the color on each click.

Comment: I vote for this answer. It's the most complete, answered the question as it was originally presented, and answered the question after it became clear what @alex.mo.07 actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle colors like this:

```
var colors = ['#3498db', '#e67e22', '#16a085', '#f39c12', '#2c3e50', '#7f8c8d', '#2980b9'];
var i = 0;

function change() {
    var x = document.getElementById("pg");
    x.style.color = colors[i++ % colors.length];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A2JBL/

Comment: What happens when he clicks the button Number.MAX_SIZE times?

Comment: The planet will explode, of course. But in reality try to calculate how long it would take to click so many times? Many, many years..

Comment: Maybe he's using a clicker script! Cookie clicker anyone? haha. I'm pretty sure most implementations use BigDecimal now which can grow to infinity (or at least until you run out of memory).